# How do I solve for the maximum acceleration?

Tags: calculus, kinematics

#### Problem

> The vertical motion of mass $A$ is defined by the relation $x = 10 \sin 2t + 15 \cos 2t + 100$, where $x$ and $t$ are expressed in $\mathrm{mm}$ and seconds.
>
> Determine:
> a) The position, velocity and acceleration of $A$ when $t = 1~\mathrm s$.
> b) The maximum velocity and acceleration of $A$.

So far I've solved for $x(t=1), v(t=1), a(t=1)$ and $V_{\mathrm{max}}$.

$
v(t) = \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} \\= 10 \sin 2t + 15 \cos 2t + 100 \\=[(10 \cos 2t)(2)]+[(15 - \sin 2t)(2)]\\=20 \cos 2t - 30 \sin 2t
$

$  
a(t) = \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt} \\= 20 \cos 2t - 30 \sin 2t \\= [(20 - \sin 2t)(2)]-[(20 \cos 2t)(2)] \\=-40 \sin 2t - 60 \cos 2t
$

$
v(t=1)=20 \cos 2t - 30 \sin 2t \\=20 \cos 2(1) - 30 \sin 2(1)\\= 18.941 ~\mathrm{mm/sec}
$

$
a(t=1)=-40 \sin 2t - 60 \cos 2t \\=-40 \sin 2(1) - 60 \cos 2(1) \\=-61.36 ~\mathrm{mm/sec^2}
$

$
x(t=1)= 10 \sin 2t + 15 \cos 2t + 100 \\= 10 \sin 2(1) + 15 \cos 2(1) + 100 \\= 115.34 ~\mathrm{mm}
$

$
0=-40 \sin 2t - 60 \cos 2t
$
$
t=-28.155 ~\mathrm{sec}
$

$  
V_{\mathrm{MAX}}= 20 \cos 2t - 30 \sin 2t \\= 20 \cos(2(-28.155))  - 30 \sin(2(-28.155)) \\= 36.0.54 ~\mathrm{mm/sec}
$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: If it's not much of an issue, I suggest typing the text of the image here. Questions where effort is shown have a much higher likelihood of receiving an answer, and you certainly have worked on this so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum acceleration happens at a point where the *acceleration's* derivative (sometimes called the *jerk*) is zero. Differentiate a third time to get
$$\frac{da}{dt}=j(t)=-80\cos2t+120\sin2t=0$$
$$-2\cos 2t+3\sin2t=0\implies t=\frac\pi2+\frac12\tan^{-1}\frac23$$
$$a_{\max}=-40\sin2t-60\cos2t=72.111\dots$$